# How to recover just deleted rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to restore table to last time with data if all data was deleted because of the repair operation. please help

Comment: Almost certainly not. You should restore from your last good backup. In any case, this is not a programming question - you might do better to ask on [dba.se]

Comment: not, its impossible !

Comment: I don't konw how to restore table, but I suggest that you should make a backup before every INSERT UPDATE DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use transaction in mysql

If you use transaction,it is possible to roll back the table.otherwise it is impossible..

Transaction syntax is here..

```
START TRANSACTION [WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT]
BEGIN [WORK]
COMMIT [WORK] [AND [NO] CHAIN] [[NO] RELEASE]
ROLLBACK [WORK] [AND [NO] CHAIN] [[NO] RELEASE]
SET autocommit = {0 | 1}
```

Comment: There is a difference between Restore and Rollback. actually OP is trying to restore deleted record after committing transaction.